# VPN subnet routing: Destination Port Unreachable

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn, libvirt

I am connected via VPN to a Ubuntu server acting as a hypervisor, running 1 VM. I can ping the VM from command-line on the server, but am unable to ping the VM via my VPN connection on my computer. All ping's return "Destination Port Unreachable"

I have a `virbr1` like this:

`virbr1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:cb:4d:9b
          inet addr:10.0.100.1  Bcast:10.0.100.31  Mask:255.255.255.224`
(created by Libvirt)

I have 1 VM running on the hypervisor with IP `10.0.100.16` which I can ping from the hypervisor, but not via VPN.

My openvpn server.conf has:

`server 10.0.1.0 255.255.255.240
push "route 10.0.100.0 255.255.255.224"`

on my client, I can ping `10.0.100.1` but I can't ping `10.0.100.16`:

`PING 10.0.100.16 (10.0.100.16) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.1.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Port Unreachable`

It appears that instead of `10.0.100.16` the ping response contains `10.0.1.1`.

When I tcpdump `tun1` on the hypervisor, I see:

`IP 10.0.1.6 > 10.0.100.16: ICMP echo request, id 26073, seq 1, length 64
IP 10.0.1.1 > 10.0.1.6: ICMP 10.0.100.16 protocol 1 port 43991 unreachable, length 92`

for some reason `10.0.1.1` is used instead of `10.0.100.16` for the ICMP reply.

Any ideas what might be wrong? Incorrect routing, missing iptables?

Comment: Use host-only networking instead of nat.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what configuration you have for the libvirt virtual network associated with the virbr0 device. The default configuration libvirt makes is to setup NAT based connectivity. In such a setup, libvirt has firewall rules that apply NAT to the outbound connections. Inbound connections are only accepted from the host OS itself - there's no routing from networks off-host, which I think will probably include your VPN connection.